# Check remembered radio button selection in for loop

Tags: django, templates

I'm trying to save in session information about picked element from list (radio buttons) and return it when I come back to page. Saved choice is stored in `picked_id` variable. I checked if it really is there by adding `{{ picked_id }}` before my `input(type="radio")` and I confirmed that view provides correct value.

Problem is that my code doesn't work. Please help me find out what's wrong with this:

```
{% if objects_list %}
<ul>
    {% for element in objects_list %}
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="object" value="{{ element.id }}" {% ifequal picked_id element.id %}checked="checked"{% endifequal %}>
        {{ element.name }}
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
    <p>{{ no_objects_mesage }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Are both elements either strings, or ints?

Comment: ints. In session I stored value which I got from request.POST['object'].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your answer:

1. You're setting the value of picked_id from the request.POST dict in your view.
2. All values in request.POST are, by default, strings.
3. The object_list is probably a list from the ORM.
4. Which means the element.id is a PK field.
5. Which is gonna be an int.

So you need to cast 'picked_id' into an int before you save it to the session.

So:

```
request.session['picked_id'] = int(request.POST.get('object', 0))
```

… or however you're doing it in your view.